# Cannot commit in Visual Studio code and git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a problem in Visual Studio Code and git
I installed Visual Studio code
I started a new directory which had code in it
I tried to commit and it told me to install Git
I installed Git 
I tried to commit and I got the following answer in the output window:*** Please tell me who you are.

> Run
>
> > git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
> >      git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity.
>   Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

I opened a Git terminal and wrote the command
Then I typed Git --list a saw that the parameters I entered
But the commit in the Visual Studio gave me the same answer
Can you help?
Ilan

Comment: I am a little confused. `Git --list` is not a correct command. Do you mean `git config --list`? If so, will you please [edit] your question to show the output of `git config --list`. Feel free to redact any sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose the `git config --global` syntax, double-check your Visual Studio Code is launched with the same account as the one you used to set those global settings.

Just in case, restart your Visual Studio Code in order to be sure it re-reads the Git settings.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into same problems.

I'm using VS Code on Linux Debian on a Chromebook Chrome OS, so it may be a little more complicated situation than yours, but it could be an option to try out.

Basically you'd need to generate SSH keys via your terminal and copy paste them onto the SSH settings on your github account.

[This video I found on youtube solved my issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXLQcX3HbWw), and now I can commit changes on git. But since this video is addressing my exact situation (chromebook linux vs code), you can just skip the chromebook specific instructions and go straight to the bash commands to generate those ssh keys, starting at around 0:45

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a Q&A site. Please add the actual answer here. The redirection off-site can stay, but only as supplemental information for the readers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem 2022, for me I had to close VS and reopen the repo and then it prompted me to enter my email and name.

After a few seconds the button became enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might have to take a look at several options first and then realize which is your problem and where it´s located. You can start by typing:

- git init, from githbash located in the folder that you want to upload.
- git remote -v, to see the version of repository used by your branch.
- git pull (yourBranch) master, to see if there are any files in your 
  git repository that are not found in your local repository.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please explain what output the user needs to look for that will help solve the original problem. Note that the OP already has a git repo, so there should be no need for `git init`.